# On the definition of the Radon measure $-\Delta u$ when $u \in H_0^1, - \Delta u \geq 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $D \subset \mathbb R^N$ be an open set and $u \in H_0^1(D)$ such that $- \Delta u \geq 0$ (as a distribution). Then $- \Delta u$ defines a Radon measure. If $w \in C_c^\infty(D)$, one can write
$$
\int_D w \ d(- \Delta u) = \langle w, - \Delta u \rangle_{C_c^\infty \times \mathcal D'} = \int_D \nabla w \nabla u. \qquad (*)
$$

So far, so good. Now, my book (*Shape Variation and Optmization*, by A. Henrot and M. Pierre) says the following:

> If $w \in H_0^1(D)$ is continuous and has compact support, one may approximate it by convolution in $H^1$ and uniformly by functions in $C_c^\infty(D)$ and pass to the limit in $(*)$ to obtain
> $$
> \int_D w \ d(-\Delta u) = \int_D \nabla w \nabla u \leq \|w\|_{H^1} \|u\|_{H^1}.
> $$

What I understand:

- Using the uniform convergence, one shows that
  $$
  \exists \ \int_D w \ d(- \Delta u) = \lim_n \int_D \varphi_n \ d(-\Delta u),
  $$
  by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.
- By the $H^1$ convergence, there is a $C^\infty$ sequence $w^\varepsilon$ such that
  $$
  \int_D w^\varepsilon \ d(- \Delta u) = \int_D \nabla w^\varepsilon \nabla u \to \int_D \nabla w \nabla u \leq \|w\|_{H^1} \|u\|_{H^1}.
  $$

My doubt is, how to put this information together to prove the claim? Or am I making some mistake?

Moreover, why does it hold that
$$
\int_K d(- \Delta u) = \int_K - \Delta u
$$
on a compact set $K$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that is meant that you get a single sequence $(w_n) \subset C_c^\infty$ with $w_n \to w$ in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $w_n \to w$ in $C_0(\Omega)$.

Comment: @gerw I fail to see why should this be true :(

Comment: You are right, this is an elementary property of convolutions